# Как убрать всплывающие подсказки при наборе в input?

Tags: html, input

Делаю строку поиска, ответы через ajax подставляются списком в блок ниже input, но при наборе браузер предлагает(подсказывает) мои прежние запросы, как можно это убрать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

задать атрибуту autocomplete значение off

```
<input type="text" name="name" autocomplete="off">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" name="name" autocomplete="off" id="name">

JS

document.getElementById('name').addEventListener('mouseenter', function(event) {
        event.target.setAttribute('autocomplete', 'off')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

В этом тысячелетии предыдущие фиксы не работают.

Решение:
К примеру, для фикса поля с адресом в качестве name нужно использовать название не содержащее подстроку 'address'.

Comment: видимо подстрока ``город`` тоже к этому относится, бесит, когда подсказка перекрывает выпадашку, в которой нужно что-то выбрать.

Answer (score 0):

```
var inp=document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for(var i=0;i<inp.length;i++){
inp[i].setAttribute('autocomplete','off');
}
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).